# What does the capacitance labels 1NF5 and 1UF2 mean on my SMD capacitor kit?

Tags: capacitor, surface-mount, capacitance

I bought an assorted capacitor kit. I know what the pF, nF, and uF labels are. However, I don't know what the capacitance of for these labeled with an extra number at the end.

I'm having problems Googling an answer, due to how generic the terms are.

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It means 1.5nF and 2.2uF. It's because printing a decimal point is unreliable since it's small so easy to rub off and easy to miss so they use the units instead.

For example in my resistor kit if they were resistors and it said 1k2, that would mean 1.2kOhms.

Answer (score 8):

As a supplement to DKNguyen answer: There are actually two non-obvious jargon things.

- The first is to use the unit instead of a decimal point. I think this predates electronics and has its roots in accounting.

In electronics, when one talks about capacitance or inductance, the unit (F or H) is almost always present. On the other hand, when we talk about resistance, the unit is almost always skipped and only the multiplier letter is used. When there is no multiplier, the letter R is used instead (3R3 = 3.3 Ohm). The letter O was replaced  because it is visually similar to 0 (zero got its slash only in the computer era).

- The second is using the letter U instead of the Greek Mu (μ) for the "micro" (1/1000000) multiplier. This practice stems from the small Latin u being similar to μ, but for your capacitors someone decided that using a capital U is a great idea as well.